# How hide group buttons in toolbar, so if press and hold on the button, will drop group

Tags: .net, wpf, button, toolbar

This type of button is often used in Blend, photoshop and other popupal applications. Usually on icon this type of button is little black corner in south-east corner!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of behaviour could be replicated by using a `Popup` with a `ListBox` to select the "currently active" button in the group.